# Problema con rutas en Laravel al pasar a servidor

Tags: laravel

tengo un proyecto de Laravel 5.6, todo bien mientras lo desarrollo, la cuestión es que en mis métodos Ajax tengo url:/ruta1/ruta2/rut3, etc y si funciona perfecto pero al desplegar al servidor, me da el error de que no existen las rutas y debo agregarles ../ lo cual cada cambio implicaría hacer todo de nuevo.

De antemano gracias!!

Comment: cómo has desplegado laravel? has copiado todo lo de public al directorio raíz del servidor y redireccionado las rutas del index.php?

Comment: si, si hice los cambios del index.php y pasé todo public a la raíz.

Comment: Hola solo para comentar que el proposito de esa pregunta era para alojar 2 sitios en un solo servidor, por defecto algunos frameworks toman la raíz como el proyecto y de ahí se derivan las rutas, por lo que el sitio sería www.dominio.com/ruta1/ruta2...
La cuestion es que yo quería tener dos proyectos y tener:
www.dominio.com/proyecto1/ruta1/ruta2
www.dominio.com/proyecto2/ruta1/ruta2
Por lo que supuse que alguna configuración de Laravel me le podría decir que no empezara después de **www.dominio.com** sino de www.dominio.com/**proyecto1**
Agradezco su tiempo! AL final los dos proyectos los pus

Comment: Hola amigos, gracias por su tiempo, solo comento que al final desplegué los dos sitios que quería alojar en servidores diferentes (Quería lograr algo como en localhost de Xampp o Wampp que se separan por las carpetas)

Comment: como le diste solucion amigo, tengo el mismo problema de rutas, solo a la raiz puedo entrar

Comment: Que hay Alberto, puedes decirme a más detalle el problema?
Si dices que solo puedes acceder a la raíz, pueden ser varias cosas, tanto de Apache como de Laravel

Answer (score 0):

En el ambiente de producción el servidor es `key sensitive`, verifica mayúsculas y minúsculas, es posible que sea eso.

Saludos!

Comment: De antemano muchas gracias por tu tiempo! no tengo problemas con los nombres de las rutas,suponiendo que visito el path: url:/ruta1/ruta2, mi path en debug es localhost/proyecto/ruta1/ruta2 pero cuando lo paso al pasarlo a producción mis rutan no se respetan y cambian a localhost/ruta1/ruta2 y me elimina el nombre del proyecto.

Comment: A qué te refieres con que en ambiente de producción es case sensitive?

Comment: @AlfredoPaz puedes checar este enlace https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensible_a_may%C3%BAsculas_y_min%C3%BAsculas

Comment: @AbrahamRosales no amigo a lo que voy es que no solo em ambiente de producción ese detalle es necesario de observar

Comment: @AlfredoPaz estas en lo cierto amigo!

Comment: Hola amigos, gracias por su tiempo, solo comento que al final desplegué los dos sitios que quería alojar en servidores diferentes (Quería lograr algo como en localhost de Xampp o Wampp que se separan por las carpetas).